# How to store multiple values in mysql table

Tags: mysql

This might be a dumb question but i hope someone either has an answer or an idea how to solve my problem. I have cdr's / Call detail records which are stored in xml files and based on type of call they can look different for every call. 
For example

```
<Features> 
<Feature>UnconditionalCallForwarding</Feature> 
<Feature>LegPartOfForwardedCall</Feature> 
</Features>
```

this call has 2 features used on call but it could be 3 or even 4. I do not wont to create a separate table to store the Features for a call as it is a performance issue to insert extra records also to clean those tables after the record has been recycled. We are talking here 1 million + records a day so performance is an issue. 
So i am wondering if it would make sense to store the list in a txt with some kind of separator which i can easily parse in an sql query.

Comment: I wager overly-long and/or variable-length rows would cause more of an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use multiple tables.  Do not store delimited text in a sql field, it undermines the purpose of the relational table structure, and creates extra work.

What you have is a one-to-many relationship.  The best way to handle it is to have a second table.  Try this example:

Table:  CallFeatures
Columns:  Id, CallId, FeatureName

Make CallId a foreign key to your Calls table.  Then you simply need to JOIN the tables when querying a call to get the features.

Note:  you will get multiple rows if you have multiple features when doing a just a JOIN query.  If you want to format your results for a report or other output format you'll need to investigate that further.  This was just a way to parse and store your features.

Comment: That is not an option because of performance and my question was not how todo a relational table as i am well aware of that. I am looking into storing possibly the values with bits but found that if there is more then 50+ possible values i get an issue with the size of nbr.

Comment: @ NoSoup4you If you aren't maintaining the data why put it into the database at all?  Why not just have your application parse the xml and spit out your reports?  You have no need for a database if you are going to "clean" your tables each time.  Also, adding the related table is still better performance wise for inserting the data then pulling it back into your reports.  You can always drop your keys and just truncate to speed up your "clean up".

Comment: The reason I need to keep them for some time as I need to keep track of usage etc and for billing. There is no way to do this via xml directly. Also I have to pull data from table to rate calls etc.

Comment: Also I will no clean the tables every time but let’s say everything that is older then 60 days will be archived or dumped. That in mind I am worried on performance of deleting every month or day records like 10 million in a 300 million table. And if I use the relational approach we can talk 50 million to delete in a 1500 million record table. I don’t think performance will be great

Comment: @NoSoup4you: Performance is not just about deleting records -- deleting is not even close to the most important or most common thing you're going to do with the data. It's also about querying. With delimited text, or even with a bit field, "number of calls that had call forwarding" is going to involve a table scan, which can take minutes or even hours. Normalized and properly indexed, it's more like seconds.

Comment: @NoSoup4you You don't think performance will be great?  By no means is 10 million a small number, but relative to a lot of systems it isn't a large number either.  I think you're creating a headache with your parsing, storing, querying functions by trying to keep these features in a single text field instead of a related table.  These will outweigh any true performance degradation caused by using the proper relational data format.

Comment: Now humor me, what performance or overhead do you think for 1 insert vs potentially 6 or 10. This sounds minimal but when you consider scaling past the 10 million records a day I want to make sure it makes sense. To be honest for long time storage i am consider couchbase as the format is way more flexible but the query option and index is not where I need it

Comment: First, you can do 6 rows a single insert.  Second, the overhead for keeping the values in the same text column is in your attempts to parse it and format, which you've mentioned you might do on both the writing to, and reading from the database. Couple that with the fact you would be maintaining what is essentially unqueryable data, you cannot actually use the field without your parsing mechanism.  It is up to you, but I am recommending this way because, from experience, it will perform as poorly as you anticipate, and it will save you a ton of headache.